# Code 3300 error while trying to save a photo to iOS album

Tags: ios, swift, photo, phphotolibrary

While trying to save a photo to a custom album on some devices we get the following error:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (PHPhotosErrorDomain error 3300).
>
> code: 3300

This is the part of the code where the issue happens

```
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                let assetChangeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: image)
                guard let placeholder = assetChangeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset else { return }
                let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: album)
                albumChangeRequest?.addAssets([placeholder] as NSArray)
            }, completionHandler: { success, error in
                completion(success, error)
            })
```

I would be thankful for any tips since I am out of ideas.

Comment: What's your image type?

Answer (score 0):

> @available(iOS 8, *)
>
> open func addAssets(_ assets: NSFastEnumeration)

have a try `albumChangeRequest.addAssets([placeholder] as NSFastEnumeration)`

---

here is the [Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phassetchangerequest/1624056-placeholderforcreatedasset)

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
let _image = image.pngData()
let assetChangeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: _image)
```